# Invalid use of group function in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get all the records but not the max id. My query is like below

```
SELECT `default_news_categories`.`title` as 'category_title',
`default_news_categories`.`slug` as 'category_slug', `default_news_categories`.`title` as

'category||title', `default_news_categories`.`slug` as 'category||slug', `default_news`.*,

`cb_users`.`id` as `created_by||user_id`, `cb_users`.`email` as `created_by||email`, 

`cb_users`.`username` as `created_by||username`, `profiles`.`display_name` as 

`created_by||display_name` FROM `default_news` 

LEFT JOIN `default_news_categories` ON `default_news_categories`.`id` = `default_news`.`category_id` 

LEFT JOIN `default_users` as 

`cb_users` ON `cb_users`.`id`=`default_news`.`created_by` 

LEFT JOIN `default_profiles` as 

`profiles` ON `profiles`.`user_id`=`default_news`.`created_by` 

WHERE default_news.id <> max(default_news.id) AND (`default_news`.`status` = 'live') 

AND `default_news`.`created_on` >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `default_news`.`created_on` DESC
```

The error which I am getting is "Invalid use of group function" and this is happening after adding **default_news.id <> max(default_news.id)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a subQuery something like this

```
WHERE default_news.id <> (SELECT MAX(id) FROM default_news)
```